# Why do some videos play with a flashing green rectangle?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

This is a MXF video file. I can play it in Adobe Premiere and it's fine, but I would like to give it to people do not have (nor want to pay for) Premiere. I was hoping to use a free program, like VLC, but I get this flashing green box within it. How do I resolve this?

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: Sometimes vlc messes up.  Have you tried other free media players, such as MPC-HC?  https://mpc-hc.org/

Comment: MPC seems to work with the videos I have tried. Is there a reason why VLC does this, or just a bug?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid.  It could be in the VLC core, or in VLC's integration with Windows, or in some goofy metadata in the video file that VLC barfs on.  If you're feeling generous, you might file a bug with the VLC developers.